# Xcode keyboard shortcut for scrolling down both cursor and line

Tags: keyboard, xcode

How can I define a keyboard shortcut in Xcode to scroll down both the cursor and the line?

In Xcode's key bindings terms, this would be equivalent to performing "Scroll Line Down (Scrolling)" followed by "Move Down (Selection)". I'm looking for a way to define a keyboard shortcut which will perform both actions at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Xcode

Assign some key combinations to the Scroll Line Up and Scroll Line Down actions:

[image]

Then install [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) and save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>XCODE</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.dt.Xcode</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>xcodearrows</name>
    <identifier>xcodearrows</identifier>
    <only>XCODE</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, KeyCode::PAGEUP, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, KeyCode::PAGEDOWN, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the KeyRemap4MacBook application, press the ReloadXML button, and enable the setting.

### Other applications

Create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this like this as `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
  "~\UF700" = (moveUp:, scrollLineUp:); // option-up
  "~\UF701" = (moveDown:, scrollLineDown:); // option-down
}
```

Then quit and reopen applications to apply the changes.

`DefaultKeyBinding.dict` stopped working in Xcode 4. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626788/custom-key-bindings-xcode-4.

This would make option-up and option-down scroll eight lines and center the view around the caret:

```
{
  "~\UF700" = (moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp, moveUp, centerSelectionInVisibleArea:);
  "~\UF701" = (moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown, moveDown, centerSelectionInVisibleArea:);
  "~$\UF700" = (moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection, moveUpAndModifySelection);
  "~$\UF701" = (moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection, moveDownAndModifySelection);
}
```

Comment: The link to KeyRemap4MacBook is dead, but that author also created https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/, which is popular these days.